# How to check if iPhone is in Airplane Mode with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, airplane-mode

I'd like to check whether flight mode is activated. If so, I need to show a warning message.

How can I check whether flight (airplane) mode is active using Swift?

Comment: Offhand, I can't think of a good reason for caring whether the device is in Flight mode.  You usually really care whether or not a network connection is available, which is a completely different question (it's a disjoint set, you can have connection in flight mode, you can have no connection when not in flight mode)  For that, take a look at [Reachability](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html)

Answer (score 13):

The easiest way is to let iOS done it for you.

to go Info.plist -> add this **Application uses Wi-Fi (Boolean) YES*

To test: Kill your app -> turn on airplane mode -> open ur app: you should be able to see alert within the app. [Tested on iPhone iOS9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrwgB.jpg)

[image: in Xcode 7]

Comment: If you find it work can u approve a correct answer ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't -- or you can't using public API. My suggestion would be to call required devices and set corresponding notifications. If you really need to know if its flight mode, maybe you can do that with calling 3G, GPS, Wi-Fi  etc. and check if every one is off.

I saw another suggestion with taking an in-app screenshot and checking for orange airplane  ( does top contains orange part ).

Drawbacks are present for both, My suggestion is bad since your devices could be off for other, not related reasons.

Good luck.

Comment: you can turn wifi on while you are on flight mode

Comment: Yeah you are right... I was just wanted to list possible devices needed for questioners purpose. Thnx for correction

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Location Services, they should return with an error code of 1009 by presenting the following in log:

```
Geocode error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1009 "The Internet connection appears to be offline."
```

If you check for a return code of -1009, you can recognize the user as offline and follow through accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You cant check the airplane mode is active or not , while you can check the cellular signal strength,

```
func getSignalStrength() -> Int {

let application = UIApplication.shared
let statusBarView = application.value(forKey: "statusBar") as! UIView
let foregroundView = statusBarView.value(forKey: "foregroundView") as! UIView
let foregroundViewSubviews = foregroundView.subviews

var dataNetworkItemView:UIView? = nil

for subview in foregroundViewSubviews {

    if subview.isKind(of: NSClassFromString("UIStatusBarSignalStrengthItemView")!) {
        dataNetworkItemView = subview
        break
    }
}

 if dataNetworkItemView == nil
 {
    return 0
 }
return dataNetworkItemView?.value(forKey: "signalStrengthBars") as! Int

}
```

Using this method you can get the signal strength and determine the device is in airplane mode or not .
In airplane mode it will return 0 while in network it will return strength.

Hope this will help you